# Dynamically inserted input elements not showing up in ActionResult's FormCollection parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am adding input elements in a view, dynamically, using JavaScript. But I am unable to find those inputs in my ActionResult's `FormCollection` parameter...:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(FormCollection fc)
```

I am able to find static input elements in the View. And using FireBug, I can see that the inputs are inside of the form element, in the DOM, and are not floating around somewhere random.

How can I access these inputs elements?

Comment: just a curiousity....Did you forget to put the "name" attribute on the dynamically generated input elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible you're doing something to keep them from getting up to the server.

- are you changing the form's Action on the client?  This causes the form values to not be posted to the server (as a browser security precaution).
- Remember to have a *name* attribute on the added elements.
- You're really posting the form, and not just refreshing?

Are the values available in the Request object?

Comment: The name attribute WAS missing. Didn't know that could have such horrible complications!... Thanks Patrick! :)